# Converting ArrayList to Array manually C#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I have done class List, which implements an array list data structure. It looks like this:

```
 class List
    {
        public int max;
        public int last;
        public int size;
        int[] arr ;
        
        public List(int n)
        {
            max = n;
            last = -1;
            arr = new int[max];
            size = 1;
        }

       
        public void addItem(int item)
        {
            if (isFull())
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Memory overflow: item cannot be added to list.");
            }

            else
            { 
                arr[++last] = item;
            }
        }
```

Can I somehow convert List to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a public method to your `List` class that returns a copy of the `arr` field:

```
public int[] ToArray() => arr.ToArray();
```

**Usage:**

```
List list = new List(1);
list.addItem(1);
int[] array = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: This solution exposes the internal `arr` member which allows modification of the original `List`'s state: `list.ToArray()[0]=123`!

Comment: @cly: Not anymore because now it returns a copy of the internal array :)